# How to put some images inside a tBOX?

Tags: graphics, subcaption, tcolorbox

How could I use subcaptionbox inside tbox?
[image]

I typed the same code outside and inside the tbox, and I obtain no images inside the tbox and a Error Message, as you can see in this image
[image]

------------------------- The code is -----------------------------

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
 \usepackage{mwe}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} 
 \usepackage{eurosym}
 \usepackage{datetime}
 \settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}   %para crear referencias
% poner las dos siguientes líneas despues de begin- document   % Type the next two lines after begin-document
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

\begin{document}

The first 3 letters are in \cref{de-dos-en-dos}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A\label{example-image-a.jpg}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}}
%
%
\subcaptionbox{B\label{example-image-b.jpg}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}}
%
%
\subcaptionbox{C\label{example-image-c.jpg}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}}
%{\includegraphics[width=.31\linewidth]{ES-P-todo-0_01-m9.eps}}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\caption{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}\label{de-dos-en-dos}
\end{figure}
\textbf{Question}
\begin{itemize}
  \item What's the letter in the middle?  
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=\large{In the next lines I'm trying to insert the same in a box, using \emph{tcolorbox} package.}]

\tcblower

The first 3 letters are in \cref{de-dos-en-dos}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A\label{example-image-a.jpg}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}}
%
%
\subcaptionbox{B\label{example-image-b.jpg}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}}
%
%
\subcaptionbox{C\label{example-image-c.jpg}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}}
%{\includegraphics[width=.31\linewidth]{ES-P-todo-0_01-m9.eps}}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\caption{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}\label{de-dos-en-dos}
\end{figure}
\textbf{Question}
\begin{itemize}
  \item What's the letter in the middle?
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put a floating environment like `figure` into a `minipage` or a `tcolorbox`. But you can use `\captionof` instead of `\caption` to put a caption text (with numbering) inside a `minipage` or `tcolorbox`. Unfortunately, `\subcaptionbox` cannot used here and has to be replaced by e.g. minipages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}   %para crear referencias
% poner las dos siguientes líneas despues de begin- document   % Type the next two lines after begin-document
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5!white,colframe=gray!75!black,
  title=Using captionof]

The first 3 letters are in \cref{de-dos-en-dos}

\begin{center}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
%
\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}%
\captionof{subfigure}{A}\label{example-image-a.jpg}%
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
\captionof{subfigure}{B}\label{example-image-b.jpg}%
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}%
\captionof{subfigure}{C}\label{example-image-c.jpg}%
\end{minipage}

\vspace{-0.25cm}
\captionof{figure}{The first 3 letters of alphabet.}\label{de-dos-en-dos}
\end{center}

\textbf{Question}
\begin{itemize}
  \item What's the letter in the middle?
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @thomas-f-sturm ok, but ..... How to obtain an image instead of the text of the fimage file?, I mean, "Graph of C" instead "example-image-c.jpg"

Comment: @MikaIke You have to remove `draft` from the `\documentclass` options. I copied that from your MWE.